# How to know which user created the GCE Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp, google-compute-engine

We have several billing enabled projects in our GCP account and each of them has several Compute Engine Instances. I want to remove non-critical instances just to reduce the unnecessary billing. But before I do that, I need to know which instance is being used for what and for that I need to know which user created it in the first place.

How do I get to know the creator of each instance either by using `Google Cloud Shell` or `Google Cloud Console`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note: I'm not a GCE user yet, the answer is based solely on documentation.

You could be [Viewing Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/audit-logging) in the `Google Cloud Console`, more specifically the [Admin Activity logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#admin-activity):

> Admin Activity logs contain log entries for API calls or other
>   administrative actions that modify the configuration or metadata of
>   resources. For example, the logs record when VM instances and App
>   Engine applications are created and when permissions are changed. To
>   view the logs, you must have the IAM roles **Logging/Logs Viewer** or
>   **Project/Viewer**.

You would be looking for the [User identities in audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#user_identities_in_audit_logs):

> Audit logs record the identity of the user performing logged actions.
>   The identity is held in the `AuthenticationInfo` field of [AuditLog](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/api/ref/rest/Shared.Types/AuditLog)
>   objects.

Ideally you'd be looking for the GCE instance creation events, but some/all of those may be too old for the logs retention policy. Then maybe search for VM instance start or other relevant events.

You could also check and maybe cross-reference the audit logs info with that from [Usage Reports](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/usage-export) or [exported billing info](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/4524336).

If this is a regular, on-going activity you may want to setup an automated [log exporting](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs) and processing pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you sorted this out, but I had to do something similar to get who started the instance so I can badger them into stopping the instance if they are not using it. I put together a Logging query:

`resource.type = gce_instance AND (jsonPayload.event_subtype = compute.instances.start OR jsonPayload.event_subtype = compute.instances.insert ) AND jsonPayload.event_type = GCE_OPERATION_DONE AND timestamp >= "2018-10-29T14:28:34-07:00" AND jsonPayload.actor.user!="" AND jsonPayload.resource.name=my-sweet-instance-name`

And here is the nodejs function I put together to get it:

```
const Logging   = require( '@google-cloud/logging' );
const moment    = require( 'moment' );

const logging   = new Logging( );




var getStartInfo = function( instanceName, querySince, cb ) {

    var tstart = ( querySince ? querySince : moment( ).subtract( 48, 'hours' ).format( ) ); // 

    var theLogFilter = 'resource.type = gce_instance AND ' +
        '(jsonPayload.event_subtype = compute.instances.start OR jsonPayload.event_subtype = compute.instances.insert ) AND ' +
        'jsonPayload.event_type = GCE_OPERATION_DONE AND ' +
        'timestamp >= "' + tstart + '" AND ' +
        'jsonPayload.actor.user!="" AND ' +
        'jsonPayload.resource.name=' + instanceName;

    logging.getEntries( {
        filter: theLogFilter,
        autoPaginate: false
    }, ( err, entries, nextQuery, apiResponse ) => {


        if ( err ) {
            console.log( "ERROR: " + err );
            cb( err );
            return;
        }

        var item, startedBy, startTime, runningTime, mostRecentStart;

        //console.log( 'Entries: ' + JSON.stringify( entries ) );
        // Mabye if none found, we try again with a longer querySince?
        if ( entries.length == 0 ) {

            console.log( "\nNo log entries found for instance '" + instanceName + "'. Filter:" );
            console.log( theLogFilter );
            cb( "No entries found" );
            return;
        }


        // Are these sorted by time?
        for ( var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++ ) {


            startedBy = entries[ i ].metadata.jsonPayload.fields.actor.structValue.fields.user.stringValue;
            startTime = entries[ i ].metadata.jsonPayload.fields.event_timestamp_us.stringValue / 1000; // This is nano seconds since epoch

        }

        if ( cb )
            cb( null, { "startedBy": startedBy, "startTime": moment( startTime ).format() } );

    } );

}
```

Hopefully that helps someone because it was a good bit of work to put together.